# how to run a shell scripts at every login in Centos

Tags: centos, bash, redhat, shell, startup-scripts

Actually i want to run my shell script at every time when a user login as well as at boot. i have tried using using crontab but it runs only at boot not at every login.so please tell  me how to do this.

```
#crontab -e
@reboot  /home/user/test.sh
```

Comment: https://github.com/jeroennijhof/pam_script may be of interest as well

Answer (score 6):

You can add your script in `~/.bash_profile` where `~` represents the homedir of the user for which running the script is intended.

Comment: That will work, as long as users don't change their shell, and/or don't edit their personal .bash_profiles.  Better would be in  in the system default `/etc/profile` or better still in an include such as `/etc/profile.d/local.sh`