# Run xterm script from /etc/profile leads to "cannot load font"

Tags: linux, centos, bash, shell-scripting, xterm

I want to auto-start a shell script and therefore I added this line to my `/etc/profile`:

```
/bin/su -c "/path/to/my/script" user -
```

the script itself starts a xterm shell command and output following error during autostart:

```
xterm: cannot load font '-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1'
```

=> if I manually start the xterm script I have no problems

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Looking at tags I assume you are using a RedHat flavour. In this case your default shell is most likely BASH and you should take in consideration .bash_profile file. https://serverfault.com/questions/782433/how-to-run-a-shell-scripts-at-every-login-in-centos

Answer (score 0):

Added the script to `~/.bash_profile` solved the problem for me. No User change is needed. (Thanks to @user2965433)

---

So just append:

```
/path/to/my/script
```

to `~/.bash_profile` of the desired user.